# TD Ameritrade "Purchase Price" not matching fulfilled order purchase price

Tags: stocks, brokerage

Under the positions portion of the TD Ameritrade website, my purchase price is being listed as "56.xx" while under the history of the order, it shows the purchase price as "49.xx" which is in line with the limit order I placed to purchase at "50". Yesterday, these boxes in positions were exactly what I expected. What is going on? I would expect the purchase price to not be able to suddenly change — I purchased it at "49.xx"! Is this some sort of bug with the site or have I missed something?

Comment: Double check your quotes and fill price.  If you haven't made an error then they have and you should call them.

Comment: How many buys of this particular stock (it is a stock, correct?) did you make?  If you made more than one buy then it will average them for your purchase price

Comment: if you did wash sale your loss would have been added to what you bought

Comment: @public wireless - That would be true for an account statement for the overall position but would not be true for a filled order ticket, aka the "history of the order" as the OP explained.